# Check if the screen has the ability to rotate?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible in Javascript to check if the screen has the ability to rotate? I don't want to know when the screen rotates, I just want to know if it can.

Comment: I think `const supportsRotation = "onorientationchange" in window` should do what you want.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.